# Recommendations for a Python game bot

Tags: python, automation, game

I want to make a *Zuma deluxe bot* to play the game and it to be based on image analysis.

**My question is:** Is python good for this task? Would the bot work fast, without delay, be efficient? I have 4 months experience in Python and I've made 3 big projects, but no one based on image recognition. I don't really want to use another language. Is something like "the program would take 10 photos per second and analyze them instantly" possible in Python. Should I start this project ? If yes, which libraries are necessary?

Comment: Python has nothing to do with image analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Python will be just fine. Take a look at [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) (CV == Computer Vision)